# List comprehension over 2 independent lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists like:

```
a = [10, 35, 57, 79]
b = [13, 41, 65, 80]
```

I want to get list with pairs of a number and value, where value is `True` for elements from the list `a`.

I can do it with;

```
a_list = [(item, True) for item in a]
b_list = [(item, False) for item in b]
result = a_list + b_list
```

Is it possible to union these two list comprehensions and make the code simpler?

Comment: Well, you can just add the lists together: `[(item, True) for item in a] + [(item, False) for item in b]`

Comment: I'd say the code is pretty much as simple to read as can be already (maybe with the exception of the comment above), trying to combine things to save code lines will probably make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest:

```
list(zip(a + b, [True] * len(a) + [False] * len(b)))
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is any more readable than the original, and it's likely to be slower.

Comment: using `chain` and `repeat` from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html would perform better than `+` and `*`

Comment: @Ruslan Tushov, Thanks! Although I tested it and the former mathod is faster by ~15%. At least for inputs of that scale, I assume with larger inputs your suggestion would be more efficient. `list(zip(chain(a, b), chain(repeat(True, len(a)), repeat(False, len(b)))))`.

Comment: Seems like a single chain would be faster: `list(chain(((i, True) for i in a), ((i, False) for i in b)))`. But I can't test it on my phone.